# How to add parameters into a url to pass data between scripts

Tags: javascript, html, url, parameters

I've been trying to add url parameters like the ones in youtube `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dJT-99KpiI` but I have no idea how to.

Relevant Node.js Server Code:

```
function(err, session) {
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    url.searchParams.append("sessionId",session.Id);
  }
```

Relevant Javascript Client-Side Code

```
url =  new URL(window.location.href);
var sessionId = url.searchParams.get("sessionId");
console.log(sessionId);
```

Comment: Been trying to add url parameters how? What code have you tried? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Dear You can pass parameters in this way

```js
function functionName(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3) {
  // code to be executed
}
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer5

Comment: Thanks  Sir "FZs" i will follow your suggestions next time

Comment: "Chava G" Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I need more context, but you can use **string literals**, for example:

```js
const id = 'Qe500eIK1oA';
const link = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${id}`;
```

or just **concat** the string with the id

```
const link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id;
```

and then you can use it like this, for example

```
window.open(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most robust way to add a query string (the `?key=value&foo=bar` part of a URL) to a URL in JS is using the built-in [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class and its [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```js
const url = new URL('https://youtube.com');
url.searchParams.append('v','1dJT-99KpiI');
console.log(url);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this but between server side and client side scripts